# Parse the json string without quotes into json

Tags: javascript, json, regex, parsing

Following json string is not converting into json as key is not inside quote.

```
{file:"http://video.test.com/media/myvideo.mp4", image:"/category/dt/filename.png", width:"100%", height:"100%", stretching:"uniform", autostart:true, modes:[{type:"flash", src:"/swf/external/player.swf"}, {type:"html5"}]}
```

I have tried:

1. JSON.parse -- it does not work as keys are not inside quotes.
2. eval('('+str+')') -- not converting for some reason, also little reluctant for this solution due to security.
3. Manually insert double quotes delimiting colon (:) but one of my
   value, which is a url, too has a colon, as given in the solution:
   [regular expression add double quotes around values and keys in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562635/regular-expression-add-double-quotes-around-values-and-keys-in-javascript)

Why is it difficult to convert this string into json and how to convert it?

```js
var s = '{file:"http://video.test.com/media/myvideo.mp4", image:"/category/dt/filename.png", width:"100%", height:"100%", stretching:"uniform", autostart:true, modes:[{type:"flash", src:"/swf/external/player.swf"}, {type:"html5"}]}';

console.log(eval('(' + s + ')'));
```

Comment: Where do you get the string from? I  would start there and try to get proper JSON.

Comment: `var result = eval('('+str+')')` should work just fine

Comment: I am extracting this string from one of the html file given by trusted third party, they can't support sending json immediately.

Comment: Can you put the code your wrote for this, so we might get an idea what  went wrong?

Comment: You say `[...]they can't support sending json immediately[...]`, but does this mean you no have any influence how they format that string? Because the easiest thing would be if they would store that sing in a proper JSON format in the HTML document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main question is really where did you get the string from, but anyways, here is a solution.

```
var obj = eval('(' + str + ')');
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: or simply `var obj = eval('(' + str + ')');`

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought that too, but I took the word of the OP for it, because it did not work.

Comment: but ... it does ... perhaps OP didn't have `var obj =` :p

Comment: yeah, it did n't work and it says 'str' is not defined, even thought its declared above it, btw, i am writing this in reactjs code using ES6 with babel. I am not sure if this blocks this style of coding.

Comment: @ParagJadhav No you cannot parse an JavaScript Object that is given as string or JSON using RegExp reliable. If the string changes for some reasons and if it contains some unexpected content, the RegExp might fail.

Comment: @t.niese No, I meant to put the quotes around the keys using regex (find a key and put quotes around it?) Would it be an expensive operation

Comment: @ParagJadhav it does not matter it it is full parsing or just a replace. Both will have that same problems. It would be a really error-prone way.

Comment: @ParagJadhav It is not reliable as t.niese has said, dedicated parsers are built for this, and JSON keys can contain other characters than simple alphanumeric, and it might include ':', which will give enough headache to where to start or stop, and also the content.